# Aptana JavaScript libraries code assist

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js, aptana

I'm using Aptana 3 for my web development, is there any way to have syntax autocomplete for jQuery, Google Maps API v3, Backbone.js etc?

Answer (score 1):

As far as jquery is concerned, go to: Commands -> Bunde development -> Install Bundle -> Jquery